# Can you still call a woman "handsome"?

Tags: meaning

On the recommendation of some regulars here, I managed to watch the movie *The Madness of King George*  over the weekend, and found it excellent.  Anyway, one funny scene in the movie is when King George, who despite being contentedly married is quite flirtatious, remarks on the looks of one of the Queen Consort's ladies-in-waiting to the head of his attending guards:

> That's Lady Penbrook. Handsome woman, what? Daughter of the Duke of Marlborough...husband's an utter rascal.

Is the usage of "handsome" here archaic, or just rarely used by those in the know? If the former, when did it become so?

Comment: I have always tried to understand the use of the word *handsome* in letter to a lady friend, but refrained from doing so, because I didn't know whether the word would be a thoughtful gesture or insulting. I have heard from many that the use of *beautiful* for a guy, when said by a woman, was also considered less than being referred to as *handsome*, but this one handsome/beautiful woman said just that: I was beautiful. Guess the meanings of both could be used either way. Nonetheless, I was honored with such deliberate grace and tone that, maybe, I should return the obligation.

Comment: I don't know how much I can add to what's already been said, but I have a family portrait photo from the late 1940's in Germany of my wife as a little girl with her aunt and uncle with whom she was staying at that time. In the photo, her aunt (my wife's mother's sister in fact) is not what I would call pretty, but she is a pleasant-looking woman, quite attractive in a robust way, and I would call her handsome. My wife, on the other hand, later when she was the same age, was what I would call *hot*. :-)

Comment: This answer doesn't really add much, but I had to share this: ![Michelle Yeoh, in the movie Crouching Tiger Hidden Dragon](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T3vua.jpg) Michelle Yeoh, in the movie *Crouching Tiger Hidden Dragon*. The epitome of handsome, in my opinion. I still get the shivers just looking at her.

Comment: Try it and find out.

Comment: You can definitely still use "handsome" for a woman, and no, it's not derogatory (at least not in the US).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Handsome* and *pretty* are two different types of human attractiveness, with *handsome* being more rugged and angular, and *pretty* being softer and more delicate.  We tend to associate *handsome* with masculine beauty and *pretty* with feminine beauty, but there are also pretty men and handsome women.  As alluded to by Brian, the use of the term might not necessarily be viewed as a compliment, since it implies a gender-atypical look.

Comment: This is purely stereotypical which has no basis in the meanings of the actual words.

Comment: Here's Merriam Webster. *Handsome*: "having a pleasing and usually impressive or dignified appearance ", *Pretty*: "attractive to look at usually in a simple or delicate way." Google's first definition for *handsome*: "(of a man) good-looking." Dictionary.com on *handsome*: "having an attractive, well-proportioned, and imposing appearance suggestive of health and strength; good-looking: ", on *pretty*, "pleasing or attractive to the eye, as by delicacy or gracefulness."  I'm not sure what characterizes the "meaning of the actual words" in your mind if not definition AND usage.

Comment: I don't see "rugged and angular" and "softer and more delicate" as necessary components of 'handsome' and 'pretty', which you have for some reason aligned with 'beautiful'.

Comment: It's only gender atypical if one starts with presupposed notions of what gender typical notions are, which can only be stereotypes.

Comment: I'm not attaching a value judgement to "typical," I'm using it in the sense of "average, common, popularly associated with."  While there is an increasing acceptance of divergence from gender stereotypes, many people still prefer to be perceived as gender typical, which is why I added the warning that not all people would receive being characterized as having gender-atypical beauty as complimentary.  It's a descriptive comment, not a prescriptive one.

Answer (score 19):

Well, the use of *handsome* in that film may well be archaic or it may not. According to NOAD it currently means

> **handsome** (of a woman) striking and imposing in good looks rather than conventionally pretty.

What I think it doesn't mean is *hot* in the sense we would use it today. The emphasis is on *striking*: she's not conventionally pretty, but neither is she ugly. She has striking features.

Here is someone I think would fit the bill rather, er, handsomely:

[image: Sigourney Weaver]

And here is someone who is more conventionally pretty:

[image: Scarlett Johansson]

But remember the worn adage about beauty being in the eye of the beholder? It's worn because it's true. There are certainly people who find Sigourney Weaver more attractive than Scarlett Johansson. And I can tell you who *I* would choose in a heartbeat if I were ever in a death match with an alien.

Comment: Right, I have heard it being used in the manner you've talked about before, but I wasn't sure if there was a hidden subtext of irony there or not.  A kind of delicate way to say "that woman looks like a man!"  In this movie, Lady Penbroke really couldn't be described as such; even with the getup and everything, she looked "classically beautiful."  First time I've fallen in love with a woman in a poofy wig.

Comment: @Billare: I think irony is in the eye of the beholder as well. Certainly you could use *handsome* to mean "not pretty"; but I think if people were looking for ways to say "not pretty" they'd go first to "plain" or some other word devoid of positive connotations. *Handsome* is, on the face of it, a compliment. It may not feel like enough of a compliment for a lot of women, but it's still positive.

Comment: Couldn't you have found a better photo of Sigourney Weaver? (I agree that she's a most handsome woman.)

Comment: Heartily agree with @Pitarou. Not a flattering photo of the actress, and the Scarlett one is really photoshopped, she looks too perfect! Me catty? *scratch* *hiss*  *miaow*

Comment: @Mari-LouA There's some amazing "portrait enhancement" software out there, and they offer free trials. Why not treat yourself? http://www.portraitprofessional.com/

Comment: @Pitarou Are you by any chance suggesting I need to enhance my looks! Tsk, shame on you! :P

Comment: @Pitarou Ack! I've just visited the site. How can anyone photoshop (enhance) an infant! And the middle-aged man looked so much nicer in the before pic than in the one after. Au naturel for me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Do you think my fur is naturally this well groomed, or my nose has quite that glossy sheen to it in real life?

Comment: I'm sure @Pitarou you are always impeccable in your appearance. Merry Xmas by the way! x

Comment: @Mari-LouA And I'm sure you're as lovely in real life as you are in your profile photo. Merry Xmas.

Comment: +1 for "fits the bill handsomely" and working in Sigourney Weaver!

Answer (score 9):

I don't know about other parts of the US, but in the South it is very common to refer to a lady as handsome.  In general it is a term used by older folks. A woman who is handsome has good looks that keep and she may have a certain chiseled quality or ruggedness that is noticed more on men, but is distinctly feminine on her. This is someone who ages well. My grandmother would always point to women 'looking handsome' at church.

Answer (score 6):

> A woman who is described as ***handsome*** rather than *[beautiful or
>   lovely](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA772&lpg=PA772&dq=causative%20as%20seems%20to%20be%20rarer%20than%20temporal%20as&source=bl&ots=7crb_aLskv&sig=3PFv2MRY3yqby_F3FZIpOuCyVjw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwB2oVChMInPfIw6LdxgIVzgWOCh2aHwjI#v=onepage&q=award&f=false)* is by implication one whose appearance aesthetically *satisfies
>   the observer* but does not markedly stir his deeper feelings.

(M-W's dictionary of Synonyms)

Answer (score 3):

I was under the impression that "handsome" was reserved for older (~50+ yo) women. Perhaps used when beauty had faded but the women retained a certain je ne sais quoi. I thinking here of Glenn Close, Sigourney Weaver or Helen Mirren.

That being said, I have not heard the term used for a while.

Comment: I agree here that 'handsome' would most likely not be used for a younger woman, no matter what her looks.

Comment: Perhaps this is a stretch but: I think the term was the polite was of saying an elegant to beautiful woman a little past her prime (post-menapausal?). These days, it would come off as both sexist and ageist with implications that a non-breeding female is not sexually desirable. "50 is the new 40", as claims the headlines.

Comment: *[Emma](http://austen.com/emma/ch1.htm) Woodhouse, **handsome**, clever, and rich, with a comfortable home and happy disposition, seemed to unite some of the best blessings of existence; and had lived nearly twenty-one years in the world with very little to distress or vex her.* She's twenty, which is some decades off from fifty.

Comment: A book published in 1815 may not be the best source when discussing contemporary word usage.

Comment: Sigourney Weaver was handsome even when she was young and at the same time she had a lot of sex appeal.

Answer (score 2):

This is a condensed version of a multitude of posted answers on The Net(that I agree with): "By a handsome woman, we understand one that is graceful, well-shaped, with a regular disposition of features.  Usually applied to a woman who is very well-groomed with the kind of refined beauty and attractiveness that requires poise, dignity, and strength of mind and character.

Answer (score 0):

The Irish song ["Tell Me Ma"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I'll_Tell_Me_Ma) includes the following line, referring to a woman as "handsome" as the first of multiple positive adjectives:

> "**She is handsome**, she is pretty, she is the Belle of Belfast city."

According to the Wikipedia article linked to above, [Sham Rock's recording of it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=So1qiyLaypk) in 1998 sold over 200k copies (>3M including compilation albums) and stayed on the UK top singles chart for 17 weeks, reaching #13.  This is a relatively recent popular example repeatedly calling a woman "handsome."  By context in the song, the woman referred to is a young woman of courting age and highly desirable ("all the boys are fightin' for her").

Comment: But this is a reviving of an old song. It hardly has a bearing on modern  conversational usage. 'Lady Madonna' is an unusual descriptor.

Comment: If millions of people are hearing and repeating its usage, it may have a bearing on modern usage (causal arrow can go either way).  Plenty of language usage (including introducing and increasing usage/meaning of words and phrases) has been shaped by popular music.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the usage of "handsome" here archaic, or just rarely used by those in the know? If the former, when did it become so?

I suggest that it is a dated phrase.  It [enjoyed some popularity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22handsome+woman%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%22%20handsome%20woman%20%22%3B%2Cc0), and you *can* say it, and if you do you bring the meanings presented in other answers, but in doing so you bring a certain stuffiness or old-fashionedness to your sentence.

As the google ngram shows, it peaked in usage in the 80's.   Since that's now over 20 years ago, it seems fair to say "it's dated".

---

note: google isn't smart with quoted phrases in its ngram urls.  If you follow the link I provided, adjust the end year to 2015 and hit "search" to see the result.

Comment: Actually, Ngram shows it rising since 2000.

Comment: Lies and statistics.   1999: 170 ; 2000: 153 ; 2008 158.   Basically a flat line after 2000, at a level a mere 20% of its popularity in the mid 80s.

Comment: When you remove the quotes you get a much different picture.

Comment: That's interesting.  I dont know what it means, but it's still a tiny climb from a low based compared to the heyday of its popularity.

Comment: Actually, the term has nearly the same popularity now that it had in 1940.  Yes, it did peak maybe 3x higher around 1900, but a lot has happened between then and now, and no term of this sort would be expected to remain static.  ("beautiful woman" shows pretty much the exact same time profile, only it's always been maybe 4x more popular.)

Comment: This is what my answer says, really.  It is **dated**.  It had a peak where it was in more popular use, and now it has fallen back to being an anachronism. 1900 is a long time ago.

Comment: But the same is true of "beautiful woman" -- is that an anachronism too?

Comment: The same is not true.  It is true that "beautiful woman" had a peak in 1900, but it was a comparitively small peak, and it's current level after the dip is not that different to the peak.  What's more, check it out with quotes.   And finally, ngram is not the ultimate decider, just useful (sometimes!?) input data.

Comment: While "beautiful woman" has re-achieved the [peak](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=handsome+woman%2Cbeautiful+woman&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chandsome%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeautiful%20woman%3B%2Cc0) it had around 1900, it was only half as popular in 1960.  So it was anachronistic in 1960?  (And when you add the quotes you totally discombobulate the data.)

Comment: And, based on your criteria, ["pretty woman"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=handsome+woman%2Cbeautiful+woman%2Cpretty+woman&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chandsome%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeautiful%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpretty%20woman%3B%2Cc0) is even more anachronistic.

Comment: Lies and statistics :)   I think you have demonstrated that ngram is not a useful tool for this appraisal.   I am stymied to present an alternative, but notwithstanding that I stick by my claim that "handsome woman" is anachronistic.

Comment: Lessee:  You originally tried to prove your point using Ngram, and now you say it's "not useful"?

Comment: Yeah yeah, I know :)   Let me say: I tried to _back up_ my point with ngram, and you foiled me somewhat on that.   I have learned some ngrammery from you, which is that things are not always as they seem there.   So I am only left with "my experience is that saying 'handsome woman' brings a dated feel to your prose".     I will just keep my eye out for evidence.   Disappointing voting seems to show that I am alone in this experience :S

Comment: Hey - I know this has gone on too long, but in 2008, "handsome woman" was 1/10th the usage of "beautiful woman".  In 1900 it was 1/4.   So it's share has been slashed.  It's dated.  (Lies and statistics).  Something really wierd happened at the turn of the century didn't it!?

Comment: You're right -- it's gone on too long.  Just because a word is slightly less popular that in a previous era does not mean it's archaic.